# Output of 'make' is a shared object and not an executable

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, shared-libraries, executable

Edit: It appears to be a g++ issue, as compiling with clang++ does output an executable file.

I've written a C++ application that has a main function, creates an application window, loads a 3D fbx file and draws that using opengl. To create the Makefile for compiling i'm using a CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(solight)
set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(lib/include)

###########################################
#SET THIS TO X32 IN CASE OF A 32 BIT SYSTEM
###########################################
set (ARCH x64)

set (SRC_LIST
    src/assetmanager.cpp src/assetmanager.h
    src/mesh.cpp src/mesh.h
    src/model.cpp src/model.h
    src/modelloader.h
    src/main.cpp
    src/math.h
    src/fbxmodelloader.cpp src/fbxmodelloader.h
    src/rendermodule.h
    src/openglrendermodule.cpp src/openglrendermodule.h
    src/textureloader.h
    src/engine.cpp src/enginemodules.cpp src/engine.h
)


##########################
#EXTERNAL LIBRARY HANDLING
##########################

set (LINUX_DEPS
    libfbxsdk.a
    pthread
    libSDL2.a
    GL
    libGLEW.a
    dl
)

set (WIN32_DEPS
)

set (APPLE_DEPS
)

if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
    set (DEPS ${LINUX_DEPS})
    set (OS Linux)
endif()

if (APPLE)
    set (DEPS ${APPLE_DEPS})
    set (OS Apple)
endif()

if (WIN32)
    set (DEPS ${WIN32_DEPS})
    set (OS WIN32)
endif()


LINK_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/${OS}/${ARCH})

####################
#EXECUTBALE CREATION
####################

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${DEPS})
```

So after running the makefile that cmake created, the output is not an executable as expected, but a shared object file. If i run the file command on it this is the output:

```
solight: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=f20c07c8743a70bca20d4a0d9f50fcb108b8140e, not stripped
```

When executing

```
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ./solight --verify
```

the program executes as it should.

**But** when i execute the file through the terminal it runs just fine, creates the window and renders the model.

Any explantion as to why this is a shared object file?
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
When running

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

the output is:

```
    /usr/bin/cmake -H/home/wouter/Documents/Solight -B/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build/CMakeFiles /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/solight.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/solight.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build'
cd /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/wouter/Documents/Solight /home/wouter/Documents/Solight /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build/CMakeFiles/solight.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
Dependee "/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build/CMakeFiles/solight.dir/DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build/CMakeFiles/solight.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build/CMakeFiles/solight.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target solight
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build'
make -f CMakeFiles/solight.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/solight.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build'
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/assetmanager.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/include  -std=c++14   -o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/assetmanager.cpp.o -c /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/src/assetmanager.cpp
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/mesh.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/include  -std=c++14   -o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/mesh.cpp.o -c /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/src/mesh.cpp
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/model.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/include  -std=c++14   -o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/model.cpp.o -c /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/src/model.cpp
[ 44%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/include  -std=c++14   -o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/src/main.cpp
[ 55%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/fbxmodelloader.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/include  -std=c++14   -o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/fbxmodelloader.cpp.o -c /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/src/fbxmodelloader.cpp
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/openglrendermodule.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/include  -std=c++14   -o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/openglrendermodule.cpp.o -c /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/src/openglrendermodule.cpp
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/engine.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/include  -std=c++14   -o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/engine.cpp.o -c /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/src/engine.cpp
[ 88%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/enginemodules.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/include  -std=c++14   -o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/enginemodules.cpp.o -c /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/src/enginemodules.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable solight
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/solight.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -std=c++14   CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/assetmanager.cpp.o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/mesh.cpp.o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/model.cpp.o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/fbxmodelloader.cpp.o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/openglrendermodule.cpp.o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/engine.cpp.o CMakeFiles/solight.dir/src/enginemodules.cpp.o  -o solight  -L/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/Linux/x64 -rdynamic -Wl,-Bstatic -lfbxsdk -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpthread -Wl,-Bstatic -lSDL2 -Wl,-Bdynamic -lGL -Wl,-Bstatic -lGLEW -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -Wl,-rpath,/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/Linux/x64 
/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/lib/Linux/x64/libfbxsdk.a(fbxutils.o): In function `fbxsdk_2015_1::FbxPathUtils::GenerateFileName(char const*, char const*)':
(.text+0x4c8): warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build'
[100%] Built target solight
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/wouter/Documents/Solight/build/CMakeFiles 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may happen when application is compiled with special `CFLAGS` e.g. `-pie -fPIE`:

```
$ echo 'int main() { return 0; }' | gcc -x c - -fPIE -pie
$ file a.out
a.out: ELF 64-bit LSB  shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24,
```

Perhaps you could run your make with `VERBOSE=1` and see if that's the case? In general `file` may use heuristics to identify filetype so you shouldn't rely on it too heavily.

As for your error with ld.so, you are using the wrong, 32-bit, dynamic linker to run 64-bit app. Use /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 instead (as `file` told you).

EDIT: Another option is that your GCC is built with [--enable-default-pie](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=e9abca4f4a48fa8b1fd9778f6a3cd748e099e3bb) which seems to be the case for [modern Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PIE). You can disable this feature by cmaking with CFLAGS=-no-pie (or -nopie, depending on GCC version) but I'd rather not do that - PIE'ed executables make your system safer by allowing ASLR to do better job.

Comment: If this is the reason (still have to test it), is there any reason why cmake would generate the makefile like that?

Comment: I'd wait for results of verbose output but I'd rather expect that your system compiler is "hardened" in some way (maybe via [--enable-default-pie](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=223796)?).

Comment: I've added the output to the question, and i have never used that option, or set is as default? How would i check this?

Comment: I have edited my question: clang++ seems to output an executable just how i want it...

Comment: Hm, `-rdynamic` is suspicious but this does not cause issues when I try to repro locally. Could you post output of `gcc -v`?

Comment: @WouterStandaert FYI it seems that `--enable-default-pie` is indeed [enabled by default on Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/PIE) nowadays.

Comment: @WouterStandaert Perhaps rename the question to mention GCC, rather CMake?

Comment: Alright i've edited the title. Anybody any idea how to turn this option off? why would they do this...?

Comment: You can try cmaking with CFLAGS=-no-pie (or -nopie, depending on your compiler). Note that I'd rather file a bug against `file` (it fails to properly discriminate between libs and apps in major distro).

Comment: As for "why" - PIEing an executable allows ASLR to make your system more safe (one of many "hardening" features of modern distros, others being default source fortification and stack protection).

Comment: Thanks you guys a lot for your explanation and help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause is the `-shared` flag in `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.
when I delete `-shared`, everything is ok.